# Jquery animation function fires on 2nd click

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#currentProject").click(function () {
        $("#projects").animate({
            height: "toggle"
        }, 800, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            $.get("<?php  echo base_url('async/projects'); ?>", function (data) {
                //alert(data[0].name);
                $("#projects").empty();
                $('#projects').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    //alert(value.name);
                    $("#newList").append("<li><a style='text-decoration:none' href='<?php echo base_url();      ?>dashboard/index/" + value.cId + "'>" + value.name + "</a></li>");
                });
            }, "json");
        });
    });
});
```

The above code works exactly as per my requirement.
The only problem is that it starts working on second click.
When I click on `#currentProject` first time nothing happens and it starts functioning from the second click.

Comment: Works here on first try..  http://fiddle.jshell.net/29MdL/

Comment: @Trevor The example u have shown is displaying the div before clicking. I want the hidden div initially.

Comment: @nagesh29 Then you just need to hide it first.  Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write your js code in the end of your document without $(document).ready

Comment: The code is already at the end of the document and checked by removing the ready function, but same situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#projects').hide();
  $("#currentProject").click(function () {
    $("#projects").animate({
        height: "toggle"
    }, 800, function () {
        // Animation complete.
        $.get("<?php  echo base_url('async/projects'); ?>", function (data) {
            //alert(data[0].name);
            $("#projects").empty();
            $('#projects').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                //alert(value.name);
                $("#newList").append("<li><a style='text-decoration:none' href='<?php echo base_url();      ?>dashboard/index/" + value.cId + "'>" + value.name + "</a></li>");
            });
        }, "json");
    });
  });
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/29MdL/1/

Comment: @nagesh29 please accept an answer if it helped you.  Or give feedback if it doesn't work or you already found a solution etc..

Comment: Is the fiddle working how you desire?  Or are you just having trouble implementing it into your project?

Comment: @nagesh29 please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've ran into this problem, these solutions worked for me,
Try using on or live, depending which version your using one or the other will work

```
 $(document).on('click', '#currentProject', function() {        

    });

 $( "#currentProject" ).on( "click", function() {

  });

  $( "#currentProject" ).live( "click", function() {

 });
```